# Excel: how to combine 3 columns into 1 row in specific order

Tags: excel, excel-2010

In Excel 2010 how can I mix 3 columns of data into one column in the specific order shown in the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with vba but there are options to keep it dynamic with formulas if you want

The following formula would be entered into a column and then copied down as far as it needs to go.

```
=OFFSET(top_left_cell,INT((ROW(A1)-first_row_output)/num_columns),MOD((ROW(A1)-first_row_output),num_columns))
```

example

```
=OFFSET($A$1,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/3),MOD((ROW(A1)-1),3))
```

What this does is it keeps the reference in the top left cell of your input table and then offsets either left or down

The column offset is controlled by MOD((ROW(A1)-1),3) which divides an incrementing number by 3 and takes the remainder.

The row offset is controlled by INT((ROW(A1)-1)/3) which divides an incrementing number by 3 and returns only the integer part of the formula.